# Python FTP filename invalid error

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file using ftp in python, but I get an error saying:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Filename invalid
```

when I run the following code:

```
ftp = FTP('xxx.xxx.x.xxx', 'MY_FTP', '')
ftp.cwd("/incoming")
file = open('c:\Automation\FTP_Files\MaxErrors1.json', 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR c:\Automation\FTP_Files\MaxErrors1.json', file)
ftp.close()
```

I've checked that the file exists in the location I specified, does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that on the server, the path `c:\Automation\FTP_Files\MaxErrors1.json` is not valid. Instead try just doing:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR MaxErrors1.json', file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to STOR needs to be the destination file name, not the source path. You should just do `ftp.storbinary('STOR MaxErrors1.json', file)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should upload file without absolute path in ftp server
for example :

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
file = open('kitten.jpg','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR kitten.jpg', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```